# Redirección de .htaccess y urls amigables

Tags: html, .htaccess

tengo una duda y espero puedan ayudarme.

He remaquetado un sitio al cual he agregado urls amigables, pero necesito redireccionar mis `urls ya indexadas en Google` a mis nuevas urls.

**Hice lo siguiente:**
Cambié mis archivos de `archivo.html` a `archivo.php`

**Use htacces para convertir mis urls a amigables:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

**Ahora necesito que mis urls antiguas redirigan por ejemplo:**

```
contacto.html --> contacto (url amigable, que ahora es contacto.php)
```

**He probado con esto pero no funciona:**

```
Redirect 301 misitio.com/nosotros.html misitio.com/nosotros
```

Y me gustaría si es posible realizarlo también con urls relativas.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondo mi propia pregunta con fines didácticos.

**Al final lo hice con:**

```
Redirect 301 /nosotros.html https://www.misitio.com/nosotros
```

Al estár en ambiente de pruebas no funcionaba, tenía que subir al servidor y al hacerlo funcionó correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías lograrlo agregando una regla para validar que la ruta termine en `.html` y estableciendo las banderas:

- [`[R]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) (redirect)
- [`[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) (last): hace que `mod_rewrite` deje de procesar el conjunto de reglas.

#### Ejemplo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Gracias por la info, pero necesito redireccionar urls específicas que desaparecieron en html